# Why is change of entropy of a mixture of water at 2 different temperatures sum of their individual change of entropy?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature, entropy

If 1kg water at 7°C is mixed with a 2kg water at 70°C, lets say that the temperature of the mixture becomes 40°C and change of entropy of water that was at 7°C is $S_1$ and that of the other is $S_2$. Then why is the total change of entropy of the systen is $S_1+S_2$ but not $S_1×S_2$ considring entropy as permutation of microstates? Or why isn't it something higher or lower than the sum as water molecules are identical?

Comment: entropy is the **logarithm** of the permutation of microstates. And $\log(xy) = \log(x) + \log(y)$. This makes entropy an *extensive* thermodynamic property

Comment: Well I was basically asking this question on the basis of Clausius' equation which is dS=dQ/T with a neglible idea of the relation between microstates and entropy

Comment: Anyways understood why is that so.....thank you @yyy

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the final temperature is 49 C.  If C is the heat capacity of the liquid water and $T_R$ is taken an absolute reference temperature for zero entropy for water, then the initial entropy of the 1 kg of water is $(1)(C)\ln{[(273+7)/T_R]}$, the initial entropy of the 2 kg of water is $(2)(C)\ln{[(273+70)/T_R]}$, and the final entropy of the 3 kg mixture is $(3)(C)\ln{[(273+49)/T_R]}$.  So the change in entropy from the initial state to the final state is $$\Delta S=(3)(C)\ln{[(322)/T_R]}-$(1)(C)\ln{[(280)/T_R]}-$(2)(C)\ln{[(343)/T_R]}$$$$=(1)C\ln{\left(\frac{322}{280}\right)}+(2)C\ln{\left(\frac{322}{343}\right)}$$Note that the reference temperature cancels out of the calculation.